# Prolog - transforming to tail recursion

Tags: prolog, accumulator

As a newbie in Prolog, I learned that tail recursion is optimized. Therefore, I am trying to convert the following program to tail-recursive ones.

```
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], N):-
    sum(T, X),
    N is X + H.
```

Here is what I've tried, and it's obvious that I missed something in my logics:

```
sum(List,Sum):-
    sum1(List,0,Sum).

sum1([Element|List],Accumulator,Sum):-
    (NewAccumulator is Accumulator + Element,
    sum1(List,NewAccumulator,Sum);

    List=[] -> Sum = Accumulator
    ).
```

The problem in my program is adding all the numbers except the last one in the list. How can I improve this program? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with TA_intern's solution, but here is an addition to show you why your program did go wrong.

The following program leaves as much of your code as possible, but is correct:

```
sum(List,Sum):-
    sum1(List,0,Sum).

sum1([Element|List],Accumulator,Sum):-
    NewAccumulator is Accumulator + Element,
    (sum1(List,NewAccumulator,Sum);
    List=[] -> Sum = NewAccumulator
    ).
```

You had `List=[] -> Sum = Accumulator`, that means that in case the tail of your list was empty, you took `Accumulator`, which is the sum of all previous elements before `Element`.

An alternative that preserves even more of your code is:

```
sum1([Element|List], Accumulator, Sum) :-
        (   NewAccumulator is Accumulator+Element,
            sum1(List, NewAccumulator, Sum)
        ;   List=[]
        ->  Sum is Accumulator+Element
        ).
```

However, I personally would prefer TA_intern's solution.

Comment: May I ask why the program is not preferable?

Comment: I didn't say it was not preferable *simpliciter*, I only referred to my personal preferences, which are of course influenced by usual practices. To me it is less readable than the other solution and I find the use of OR (`;` often rather confusing.  The use of `->`also makes it confusing to me. I think that in terms of efficiency, both solutions are basically on a par, so the only reason for my preference really is readability.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it! It's helpful for me to know since I am trying to improve the readability and efficiency as well.

Comment: Would you mind using a standard indentation?

Comment: @false: what do you mean?

Comment: Say `listing(sum1)` (should you use SWI) and use that indentation. A semicolon at the end of a line after some goals is really a nono.

Comment: Done. However, now the similarity to the code presented in the question is not obvious any more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you wrote the program wrongly. This would be correct:

```
sum(List, Sum) :-
    sum_1(List, 0, Sum).

sum_1([], Sum, Sum).
sum_1([H|T], Sum0, Sum) :-
    Sum1 is Sum0 + H,
    sum_1(T, Sum1, Sum).
```

but you could have googled some version of this here on stackoverflow.

This is also trivially a fold on a list:

```
sum([H|T], Sum) :-
    foldl(add, T, H, Sum).

add(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.
```

Comment: Thank you! But, may I ask what's the logic of  `sum_1([],Sum,Sum).`? Meaning what's the difference between putting into the if else block and make it the base case?

Comment: @Woden this is how accumulators work: "when the list is empty, the accumulator _is_ the sum".